# Why doesn't g++ pay attention to __attribute__((pure)) for virtual functions?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, virtual-functions

According to [the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), `__attribute__((pure))` tells the compiler that a function has no side-effects, and so it can be subject to common subexpression elimination.

This attribute appears to work for non-virtual functions, but not for virtual functions.  For example, consider the following code:

```
extern void f( int );

class C {
 public:
   int a1();
   int a2() __attribute__((pure));
   virtual int b1();
   virtual int b2() __attribute__((pure));
};

void test_a1( C *c ) {
   if( c->a1() ) {
      f( c->a1() );
   }
}

void test_a2( C *c ) {
   if( c->a2() ) {
      f( c->a2() );
   }
}

void test_b1( C *c ) {
   if( c->b1() ) {
      f( c->b1() );
   }
}

void test_b2( C *c ) {
   if( c->b2() ) {
      f( c->b2() );
   }
}
```

When compiled with optimization enabled (either -O2 or -Os), `test_a2()` only calls `C::a2()` once, but `test_b2()` calls `b2()` twice.

Is there a reason for this?  Is it because, even though the implementation in class `C` is pure, g++ can't assume that the implementation in every subclass will also be pure?  If so, is there a way to tell g++ that this virtual function and every subclass's implementation will be pure?

Comment: I notice that __attribute__((nothrow)) also behaves the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking into g++'s internals, I suspect it's because g++ can't assume that every subclass's implementation will be pure (like you said).

Can you turn `b2` into a non-virtual pure wrapper around a virtual non-pure method?